# SQL for aggregating customers by country

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to write some SQL to aggregate (count) how many customers I have per country. So far I have made the easy query to count how many users there are in a specific country. for example:

```
SELECT count(customerID)
FROM contact_info
WHERE country = 'United States'
```

however what I really want is one script that will return a table of two columns. One column being country and the other column being how many customers live there. The ER diagram for my database is below, as you can see the country information is in the contact_info table. All help is greatly appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Just about any SQL tutorial should explain how to do this, it's one of the most common operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Group by country`. What it'll do is create a country-wise group along with all the columns. Then do the `count()` on `customerid`. So, it'll count all customers within a group of a particular country.

```
SELECT country,count(customerID)
FROM contact_info
group by country;
```

Comment: Maybe a little less it'll